# One ticket bought with miles on multi- carrier; how to buy the same ticket for a spouse?

Tags: tickets

I am taking a business trip to Hong Kong....flying JFK to HKG....and want to go business class. I hope to use miles to pay for my wife's ticket.  I found a good itinerary for her through Delta, JFK to HKG on China Air, and returning HKG to JFK on Korean Air using miles.  Question: how do I book tickets for me (using $$)on China Air outbound and Korean Air return?  Call a travel agent?

Answer (score 3):

Simply ask the Delta agent to book you a paid ticket on the same flights. They can tie the two reservations together, so any airline imposed changes apply to both bookings.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by "China Air" you mean Air China the mainland airline (rather than China Airlines the Taiwan carrier), I had no problem booking it on Orbitz with a few extra clicks. Kind of expensive though ($10K) vs. $5K-ish on China Air return (both for business class).

Comment: He probably means China Airlines as they are code share and frequent flyer partners with Delta.